# Help me understand Exchange and mail routing

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

The organization responsible for our mail infrastructure has recently embarked upon a migration to Microsoft Exchange.  The group I work with has encountered some problems with the Exchange implementation.  Because there are political issues involved here as well as the technical ones, I'm looking for a little help understanding how Exchange operates before I go to the IT folks.

Exchange is currently hosting the `example.com` subdomain.  We have applications on hosts within this domain that expect to receive email directly.  Due the local mail routing infrastructure, email from *outside* of our organization to, for example, `user@machineA.example.com` works just fine...but mail sent to the same address from within the Exchange environment bounces with the following error:

```
#554 5.4.4 SMTPSEND.DNS.NonExistentDomain; nonexistent domain ##
```

This happens regardless of whether or not there exists an `MX` record for the target host.  It appears that Exchange believes that it is unilaterally responsible for both `example.com` *and* all subdomains thereof.

Is this fundamental to the behavior of Exchange?  Is there a way to configure Exchange so that it Does The Right Thing according to [RFC2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), even for subdomains of the domain for which it is the primary mailserver?

Comment: My understanding of Exchange is that it wants to run the domain and everything under it but I do not speak from an authoritative position. In cases like this, I might consider a separate MTA which manages the domain and sub-domains, and let Exchange do the internal stuff only.

Comment: @larsks - Which version of Exchange are you using (I'm thinking 2007 or 2010 from that message)? Also, what's the tl;dr of that RFC .. I don't have the will to read it :) Sorry but you'll have to spell out exactly what your desired behaviour is for me.

Comment: @Randolph: I would consider that, too, but unfortunately this wasn't my decision or responsibility.  All we can do is hope to understand it :).

Comment: @Ben: That would be the SMTP RFC, which I figure will be familiar to folks in a position to answer this question.

Comment: @larsks - Unfortunately you figure wrong. I can go on for hours about Exchange (look at the top users for the various [exchange] tags), but to be perfectly honest I don't read through the RFCs.

Comment: @larsks: Standards + Microsoft people = P(snowball + hell) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in our case the problem boils down to the fact that Active Directory is configured to be authoritative for DNS requests in the `example.com` domain, even though technically it shouldn't be...so the error message being returned is fundamentally accurate; AD doesn't know about `hostA.example.com` even though the resource record exists in the organization *real* authoritative nameservers.  I guess we'll be taking this up with the AD folks.

Comment: Good spot. I think if you accept your own answer, this will settle the matter. I've voted you up.